# Is there a VB.NET equivalent of the VB6 Support.TabLayout Method?

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

I'm currently tidying up some converted VB6->VB.Net code at work, but I'm trying to find the .Net equivalent of the Support.TabLayout Method without much luck:

```
Debug.Print(VB6.TabLayout(intPages, lngColumn, .ColPageBreak, .Text))
```

Does anyone know of the equivalent or alternative to this method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an untrivial method to replace, nothing close in the regular framework.  Avoid burning too much effort on a debugging aid.  A simple direct translation could be:

```
    Debug.Print("{1}{0}{2}{0}{3}{0}{4}", vbTab, "one", 2, "three", 4)
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using the `String.Join()` method passing the tab character as a separator and an array of values to join?